# Reformulation of logistic regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, classification

[image]

I am given the question above and can't seem to get the form that it's asked for. I have tried working it backwards from the goal which gives me:

```
log(1 + e^(y_i * t_i)) - log(e^(y_i * t_i))
```

This is different from the form that's taught in textbooks: [image]

I may be missing something very obvious. Any help or hints are kindly appreciated

Comment: There is a typographical error in the question: the sum's index is $i,$ not $n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$P(t_i=1|x_i)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-y_i}}\rightarrow P(t_i=-1|x_i)=1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-y_i}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{y_i}}$$
The closed form for both $t_i\in\{1,-1\}$ is:
$$P(t_i|x_i)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-t_iy_i}}=\sigma(-t_iy_i)$$

The negative log-likelihood of the data is:
$$NLL=-\sum_{i=1}^n \log P(t_i|x_i)=-\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma(-t_iy_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\log (1+\exp(-y_it_i))$$